# Heroku docker: Error on Mac apple silicon based processors

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, heroku-cli

So, my local docker environment all works fine with docker hub desktop app. But when I try to deploy to heroku using

```
heroku container:push web -a your-app-name
```

It gives an error saying

> unsupported: unsupported architecture arm64
> ▸    Error: docker push exited with Error: 1

On researching, I found that heroku does not support building from arm64. Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 6):

A workaround that I found useful was to build the image using the Docker CLI under linux/amd64 architecture, tag and push to the appropriate Heroku URL, then release using the Heroku CLI.

```
docker build -t app-name --platform linux/amd64 .
docker tag app-name registry.heroku.com/app-name/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/app-name/web
heroku container:release web -a app-name
```

Comment: Your first command does not work on my local, gives ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument. But docker buildx build -t app-name --platform linux/amd64 . works

Comment: @boyaronur, thanks for the correction. I was indeed missing the dot in the build line which is a required argument indicating the build should occur off the current directory. My answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also include the platform in your Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ...
```

Then just a matter of push your image

```
$ heroku container:push app_name:latest
```